# How can I change the css style in another component by clicking the button?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

I have developed a component test1 which contains a button and a `<p>Hello World</p>`. When I click on the button the background color of the paragraph changes. But now I want to change the background color in app.component when I click on the button. I tried to solve the problem with @Input, but unfortunately it does not work yet. Can you please help me? [My Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sen4jj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

My code:

```
// test1.component

// HTML
<button type="button" (click)="testHandler()">Change Color</button>
<p [class.toggled]="classToggled">Hello World</p>

// CSS
.toggled {
background-color: blue !important;
}

// TS
public classToggled = false;
testHandler() {
this.classToggled = true;
}
```

```
// app.component

// HTML
<div class="wrapper" [class.test1]="classToggled">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

// CSS
.test1 {
  background-color: red !important;
}

// TS
 @Input()  public classToggled = false;
```

Comment: your component test1 is inside app component right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then instead of Input decorator you could use Output and emit the value.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it.

For unrelated components, you could use a singleton service to share a styling object between the components and bind it using `[ngStyle]`.

**styling.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class StylingService {
  sharedStyleSource = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  public sharedStyle$ = this.sharedStyleSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  newStyle(value: any) {
    this.sharedStyleSource.next(value);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { StylingService } from './styling.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private styling: StylingService) { }

  onClick() {
    this.styling.newStyle({ 'background-color': 'blue' });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<button (mouseup)="onClick()">Change child style</button>

<app-test></app-test>
```

**test.component.ts**

```js
import { StylingService } from '../styling.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(private styling: StylingService) { }
}
```

**test.component.html**

```html
<p [ngStyle]="(styling.sharedStyle$ | async)">
  test works!
</p>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pk8nmm?file=src/app/test/test.component.html)

Comment: I have looked at your example and have some questions. Is it also possible to implement the button in test.component and change the colors by clicking parallel the paragraph in test.component and a div from app.component?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use ngClass and pass a parameter.
[NgClass Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)