# How to change iframe src with onclick event from another component (angular)

Tags: angular, iframe, src

Can anyone help me on how to change the src attribute of iframe when a user click on an element from another component's template? I've spent hours battling with this. Here is an image of what I'm trying to achive

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction ?

Comment: For a quick fix, you could setup a singleton service to share the event emission between components.

Comment: @Michael D, can you share a hint on how I can do that?

Comment: @Timothy: There are multiple related answers. You could even refer two of my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977074/6513921 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806453/6513921